# Matlab's specgram outdate vs spectrogram replace

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, spectrogram

In Matlabs recent versions, the `specgram` function is being replaced by `spectrogram`, and the documentation states:

> **Note.** To obtain the same results for the removed specgram function, specify a 'Hann' window of length 256.

Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work for me, if I use `spectrogram(signal,hann(256))`, the result is different from `specgram(signal)`, although both are quite similar. Is there a way to get the exact same output?

Answer (score 4):

Well, I just stumbled upon the solution:

`specgram(singal) = spectrogram(signal, hanning(256))`

since `hann` and `hanning` aren't the same thing in Matlab.

Thanks everyone for the support.

Answer (score 3):

I believe they are computed a bit differently in each function. This is the best I could obtain:

```
sig = rand(1280,1);
Fs = 2;
nfft = 256;
numoverlap = 128;
window = hanning(nfft);

%# specgram
subplot(121), specgram(sig,nfft,Fs,window,numoverlap)

%# spectrogram: make it look like specgram
[S,F,T,P] = spectrogram(sig,window,numoverlap,nfft,Fs);
subplot(122), imagesc(T, F, 20*log10(P))
axis xy, colormap(jet), ylabel('Frequency')
```

[image: spectrogram]

Answer (score 1):

I don't currently have Matlab to try, but [`hann(256,'periodic')`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/signal/hann.html) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I would be surprised because if you look at the source code of specgram `edit specgram.m`, you will find around line 133 that its using the older HANNING function instead of the HANN function (although both are the same and defined as `0.5*(1-cos(2*pi*n/nfft))`) with 'symmetric' as the default option